# Google Closure Compiler: Problem with programmatic access

Tags: php, jquery, api, curl, google-closure-compiler

I'm attempting to access the [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) tool [programmatically](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial1.html), but having issues both with PHP and JavaScript.  Here is a quick and dirty PHP script I whipped up just to play around with the compilers' REST API:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre><br />';
  foreach ($_POST as $k => &$v) $v = urlencode($v);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile');
  echo curl_exec($ch);
} else {
  echo "
    <html>
      <body>
        <form action='' method='post'>
          <p>Type JavaScript code to optimize here:</p>
          <textarea name='js_code' cols='50' rows='5'>
            function hello(name) {
              // Greets the user
              alert('Hello, ' + name);
            }
            hello('New user');
          </textarea>
          <input type='hidden' name='compilation_level' value='WHITESPACE_ONLY' />
          <input type='hidden' name='output_format' value='json' />
          <input type='hidden' name='output_info' value='compiled_code' />
          <input type='hidden' name='warning_level' value='VERBOSE' />
          <br /><br />
          <input type='submit' value='Optimize' />
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>";
}
```

The output I see is:

```
Array
(
    [js_code] =>               function hello(name) {
                // Greets the user
                alert(\'Hello, \' + name);
              }
              hello(\'New user\');

    [compilation_level] => WHITESPACE_ONLY
    [output_format] => json
    [output_info] => compiled_code
    [warning_level] => VERBOSE
)

Error(13): No output information to produce, yet compilation was requested.
```

I thought, maybe there's a problem with my [cURL options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).  So I tried JavaScript (via a [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call).  I "[jQuerify](http://firequery.binaryage.com/)"d a random Firefox window and ran the following code in the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console:

```
$.post('http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile',
  {
   'js_code': "function hello(name) {/*Greets the user*/alert('Hello, ' + name);}",
   'compilation_level': 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
   'output_format': 'text',
   'output_info': 'compiled_code'
  },
  function(response) {
    alert(response);
  }
);
```

The "Net" panel shows a 403 error for this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to API docs

```
The request must always have a Content-type header of application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Didn't see that in your code

Add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
```

before `curl_exec()`

Answer (score 1):

Ajax (*via jQuery or otherwise*) will not work because of same-origin policy. (*ajax requests are restricted in same domain, unless jsonp is expected as result*)

Simply using your example to post the info, it works as seen in http://www.jsfiddle.net/RySLr/

So it must be what @German Rumm mentions..

Comment: Duh.  I should have realized this.  Thanks!